# Single Sign On (SSO) from Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, single-sign-on, kerberos

I am trying to get single sign on working from Firefox version 3.6.6 running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx to IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008.

If I type
**kinit**
then
**kinit -S HTTP/mydomain.com**
the resulting in a **klist** that looks like this

---

Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_2040529396
Default principal: administrator@MYDOMAIN.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
07/24/10 18:20:26  07/25/10 04:20:29  HTTP/mydomain.com@MYDOMAIN.COM
renew until 07/25/10 18:20:26

---

And single sign on to a website on mydomain.com works **perfectly.** Yippee!

But if I type
**kinit**
then
**kvno HTTP/mydomain.com**
resulting in a **klist** that looks like this

---

Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_2040529396
Default principal: administrator@MYDOMAIN.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
07/24/10 18:23:42  07/25/10 04:23:47  krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.COM@MYDOMAIN.COM
renew until 07/25/10 18:23:42
07/24/10 18:24:10  07/25/10 04:23:47  HTTP/mydomain.com@MYDOMAIN.COM
renew until 07/25/10 18:23:42

---

then navigating to a website on mydomain.com prompts for username and password  :-(

It looks to me as if firefox is just taking the first ticket from the cache that matches   the domain name
(ie the krbtgt ticket) rather than the correct HTTP ticket. Could that really be the   problem???

I would **LOVE** some help. Does anyone recognise this problem? Does anyone have an idea as to how I can go about further diagnosing the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had foolishly added a firefox configuration (about:config) entry to network.negotiate-auth.delegation.uris. Returning this value to the blank default got everything working smoothly.